# What spell was Gandalf summoning in The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies?

Tags: movie, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, gandalf, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

In the movie the Hobbit Battle of Five Armies, during Gandalf captivity in Dol Guldur (inside the cage), he and Radagast were whispering a spell, what kind of spell is that and what does it do?

[image]

Comment: There's no help in the commentary.

Comment: Can I get copyright on the "**Because the films are nonsense**" comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radagast is whispering part of his healing spell (from healing Sebastian the Hedgehog in AUJ). Specifically, he's saying "Na coilerya en-vinyanta", which is Quenya for "Let (your) life be renewed." So Radagast is trying a little at-a-distance Wizard First Aid. I've been unable to find a direct transcript of what Gandalf is whispering. My first assumption was that it was some sort of healing or protection spell, but over time I started thinking that it was a call for help (to either Radagast or Galadriel) in Sindarin or Quenya. Someone on another site said that they watched the film in China, and the subtitles while he was in the cage read "Valar, please come and protect me," so it's probable that Gandalf is actually praying for help rather than casting a spell.

Comment: Do you have a source for what Radagast said? If so please link to it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I got the majority of Radagast's spell from this page on "Ask About Middle Earth," http://askmiddlearth.tumblr.com/post/66465193900/radagasts-spell. However, their transcript is in the wrong order and isn't complete: It goes: Lerya laman naiquentallo, kelva melde, Sí a hlare ómaquettar,Na coilerya en-vinyanta. The "kelva melde" means "my dear/beloved animal," and I knew that from watching the film and knowing a little pidgin Quenya from the Silmarillion.

Comment: Please edit that into your answer, and in the future please be sure to link to all sources in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

My thought was that it was a quieter version of the same spell of opening he tried using on the doors of Moria's secret entrance in The Fellowship of the Ring, in an attempt to get the cage door open.

Comment: He should have tried - Alohomora!